# Setting up Pytorch in Venv for both CUDA and ROCm

Tags: pytorch, python-venv, amd-rocm

I want to install PyTorch on multiple different machines with different hardwares, using both CUDA and ROCm hardware, but I'm not sure how to setup a venv that works for both, so to have as simple an environment solution as possible for all.

I've only searched online to see if there's anyone that has had similar problems before. I couldn0t find anything

Comment: To clarify, you're looking for something that figures out if your computer supports CUDA or ROCm, then you want to download and install the relevant version of Pytorch? Or do you have computers with both NVIDIA and AMD GPUs simultaneously?

Comment: Neither exactly, perhaps the question is fundamentally flawed I'm coming to realize.

I want to setup a venv such that when exported and passed between machines with different PyTorch backends, be they CPU, CUDA or ROCm, the all play nicely.

I'm coming to think that its fundamentally misguided to ask venv to do this and i shpuld instead set them up manually before, and then setup the rest of the venv

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to make:

On the CUDA machine:
1 virtual environment
1 file requirements_CUDA.txt with the related pytorch version
install with:
`pip install -r requirements_CUDA.txt`

On the ROCm machine
1 virtual environment
1 file requirements_ROC.txt with the related pytorch version
install with:
`pip install -r requirements_ROC.txt`
i